# UIPickerView in UITableViewController view - scrolling problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a pickerView in the UITableviewcontroller. When the user clicks on theUITextfield the pickerview pops up and works fine. But after the done action is performed the UITableview wont scroll till the botteom. What problem it could be. I used Apple's UIPicker sample code. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks